# Jquery in 30 days inquiry

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently watching a tutorial video "30 days to learn jQuery".
I have a question about why the tutor in the video **returned a variable** from a function.

Here's the code:

This is in the HTML file which just binds an event handler to buttons, calls functions, etc.

```
(function() {

    slider.nav.find('button').on('click', function() {
        slider.setCurrent( $(this).data('dir') );
        slider.transition();
    });     
})();
```

and this is the one function I'm interested in (in the js file):

```
Slider.prototype.setCurrent = function( dir ) {
    var pos = this.current;

    pos += ( ~~( dir === 'next' ) || -1 );
    this.current = ( pos < 0 ) ? this.imgsLen - 1 : pos % this.imgsLen;

    return pos; // <== HERE

};
```

The only thing I want to figure out is why `return pos`? I tried removing it and the code still worked.

Was it a mistake or is there sound logic to this?

In a nutshell, `setCurrent` function is called and `setCurrent` returns a value. But why?

Comment: I guess he had a use for it. All it means is that calling `setCurrent` will also tell you which index it changed to, which could (potentially) be useful for displaying extra information, such as text overlays. But in the code above you don't use the return value, so returning nothing is equally valid. The convention in jQuery is to return `this` (to allow chaining) but it's really up to you, and your circumstances.

Comment: this line is super-bizarre though `pos += ( ~~( dir === 'next' ) || -1 );`. I'm pretty sure he's saying `pos += (dir === 'next') ? 1 : -1;`, but with all the syntax abuse it's hard to tell...

Comment: @Dave, Indeed.  I have never seen the `~~` operator in js before

Comment: @Dave: `dir === 'next'` returns true/false, so `~~(dir === 'next')` converts true/false to numeric form (1/0). `~` is bitwise NOT operator.

Comment: @nhahtdh I know it's bitwise not, but why anybody would ever use `~~` is beyond me (if he did it to convert to number he would have been better off using the unary `+`). It leaves me thinking he had some specific hack in mind, but maybe it's just bad code.

Comment: @Dave Looks like code that is too smart for its own good

Comment: in the video he explains that by using double tilda is a way to execute with less lines of code but you will seriously lose readability. he used an if statement first, then ternary just to show us various techniques, but again..readability is harsh.lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know without seeing the rest of your code, but often functions that set a value on object will return something, even though that is counterintuitive, since their purpose is to set a value, not to get something.

The most common pattern you'll see is to return the object itself.  The allows you to chain together multiple setter calls at once:

```
object.setColor("red").setSize("large");
```

This is not specifically going on in your case, but the author may have had a similar use in mind, in the sense that he wanted to do 2 things at once: set a value, and get some information about how that value was set.

Comment: @asifrc and jonah thanks, i think the getter/setter idea maybe what he intended.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speculate as to why your tutor did that, but a common practice, especially in jQuery, is to overload a function by having the same function be both a setter and getter based on what parameters are passed. An example is below:

```
function (dir)
{
    //If dir was passed as a parameter
    if (typeof dir !== "undefined")
    {
        //Setter code
        value = dir;
    }
    //Getter (always returns value)
    return value;
}
```

There are tons of functions in jQuery that use this, e.g `.val`, `.height`, `.css('propertyName', [optionallySetValue])`, etc.

Let me know if this makes sense, or if you have any questions :)